# forcing landscape mode on a tablet

Tags: android

I have an activity which must always be launched in landscape mode. In my `onCreate()` method, I use the dimensions of the screen (width and height) to set up the interface, so it is important that the activity is not initially created with the wrong orientation.

To do this, I have the following in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="app.myapp.WideActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="landscape"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

This seems to work completely fine on my phone, but on my tablet (samsung galaxy tab, android 3.1) the activity is launched in portrait mode and switches orientation almost immediately (after the `onCreate()` method - it seems). On my phone (android 2.3) the screen is already landscape before the onCreate() method is called.

Putting `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`
 in the onCreate() method does't seem to help. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can fix the exact problem. It seems for me the problem is in samsung's implementation of activity/window management framework part. 
However, you can try to prevent a crappy UI to appear by delaying the rendering.

In onCreate() show some default layout - just a plain black layout stretched to the entire screen.
In onResume() check the screen orientation, if it is not landscape then you post a delayed runnable which will apply your layout (setContentView(my_UI)).
Inside the runnable you also check if screen orientation is landscape, and re-post the runnable if orientation is still portrait, otherwise set the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does seem like strange behavior, it seems to handle portrait correctly but not landscape. I think for my application I can just check the orientation and swap the height and width values if necessary. This makes my activity display correctly.

Comment: Actually, now I think about it, if I were to remove the `configChanges="orientation"`, the onCreate() method would be called again when the device switches orientation and the UI would fix itself. Could also add a check in the onCreate method and not draw the UI at all in portrait mode